# why does $X,Y \in L^2 $ and $E[X^2]=0 \implies X=0$ everywhere and not almost surely

Tags: probability-theory

If $L^2$ denote all (equivalent classes of almost sure equality) random variables $X$ such that $E[X^2] < \infty $. Note here we are identifying all random varibles $X,Y$ in $L^2$ that are equal a.s and we consider them to be the representatives of the same random variable . Then why does this have the consequence that if  $E[X^2]=0 \implies X=0$ everywhere and not almost surely .

Since $X \in L^2$ identifies all random variables Y s.th $X=Y$ a.s then $E[X^2]=0 \implies Y=0$ a.s $\forall Y$ s.th $Y=X$ a.s and since if  $Y(\omega_i) != 0$ for some Y then we can always find another $\overline{Y}$ s.th $\overline{Y(\omega_i)}=0$ and we can therefore conclude that $X(\omega)=0$ $ \forall \omega \in \Omega$

I am actually not convinced with this argument . Could somebody make it more formal(or fix it)
Thanks

Comment: In general, you only get equality with $0$ a.s. Nevertheless, inside the equivalence class of $X$ you may find a continuous representative, in this case the function $0$ itself. When one rushes to communicate results, there is always this ambiguity between  equivalence class and representative.

Comment: To be more concrete: If $X=0$ everywhere except at some point $x$ where it is $1$, clearly $E(X^2)=0$, yet $X \neq 0$.

Comment: @AlexM. What do you mean by "inside the equivalence class of X you may find a continuous representative, in this case the function 0 itself." I do not follow you .

Comment: What Alex M. means is that the random variable $X$ that is _always_ $0$ represents the same random variable as any $Y$ with $E[Y^2]=0$. So you pick that one to represent the equivalence class.

Comment: @Arthur your last comment clears my doubt . Thank you so much